# Multiple named capturing group with the same name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use the replace() method to replace a substring of a larger string.
My regex is 
 `#(?:[%$]([A-z0-9a-z]+)|([A-z0-9a-z]+))`
 so i either match #$string123 or #string123 (these strings are a substring of a longer string), i wish to replace the "string123" part keeping the previous '#' or '#$', i was thinking about using named capturing groups and then use the replace() method to only replace the named capturing group, but of course i can't have multiple capturing groups with the same name otherwise i could just have 
 `#(?:[%$](?<to_change>[A-z0-9a-z]+)|(?<to_change>[A-z0-9a-z]+))` 
 and it would have been fine.

Finally my question is, is there any way to have multiple capturing groups with the same name, or is there another way to do this that i don't know?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a typo in your regex? The first `+` is inside the group, right? `#(?:[%$]([A-z0-9a-z]+)|([A-z0-9a-z]+))`?

Comment: Yes it is inside the group actually, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the `#` and make the dollar sign optional instead of using an alternation. In the replacement use group 1 followed by the replacement.

```
(#\$?)[A-Z0-9a-z]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9KvXXH/1)

```js
const regex = /(#\$?)[A-Z0-9a-z]+/g;
const str = `#\$string123
#string123`;
const result = str.replace(regex, "$1replacement");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I'm still kinda new on regex and didn't think about making the dollar optional, now i have this regex `(#(?:\$?|\%?))[A-z0-9a-z]+` (it has to work with either #$ or #%) and it substitutes _#$string123_ to _#$new_string_ and this is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: You are welcome. I have updated the pattern as `A-z` should be `A-Z`